# Adjust column width dynamically with column grouping and scrollX in Datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I added column grouping and hide/show of columns using datatable's extension Buttons api. After adding fix header using `scrollX:true` columns width are not adjusting by itself. Visible column inheriting Group `th` width. Please found following link, http://live.datatables.net/butofamo/1/edit. View output in full screen.

So my expected result is fix width of Group1 header as 'Name' column size and adjust 'Group2' width size accordingly.

Comment: What behavior do you expect when there are only 2 columns, should table shrink?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com No, not at that time. Table size is 100% of container. So it will consume whole table.

Comment: This occurs because width of the table is set to 100%. If you set container to smaller width, it will not occur, see http://live.datatables.net/butofamo/2 . Not sure if it would be possible to shrink the table with `scrollX: true`.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com But our design is responsive, so we cant use fix width.

Comment: I understand, please elaborate more on what is your expected behavior if there are only two columns?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com If there are only two columns then it will consume whole table size. 50% for each column in 100% width.